How can I place an item in a non-dynamic grid (defined in an ItemsControl) using a binding for parameters such as grid.column and grid.row?
I have a problem for you.
I would like to create a schedule similar to the Outlook calendar in C#.
I want to place blocks of color (or colored borders) in an already defined grid with 7 columns and 96 rows (the 24 hours divided into quarters of an hour).
I'm using MVVM architecture. In my ViewModel, I have an “Activite” class defined as follows.
public class Activite
{ 
    public int Jour { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan HeureDebut { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan HeureFin { get; set; }
    public string NomActivite { get; set; }
    public int? Couleur { get; set; }
    public int ColonneJour => (int)(Jour - 1);
    public int LigneDebut => (int)((HeureDebut.TotalMinutes / 15) - 1);
    public int LigneFin => (int)(((HeureFin.TotalMinutes / 15)) - LigneDebut) + 1;
}

“ColonneJour” represents the column number in the grid.
“LigneDebut” represents the row where the block is to be placed.
“LigneFin” represents the number of rows over which the block should extend.
This class is used to create a list of activities (“ObservableCollection”) containing the required data.
I want to inject this list, item by item, into the grid below. But the items don't appear. I've tested this by putting the parameter definition in the Border instead of the ItemContainerStyle, but it doesn't change anything.
You can see the WPF code below.
<Grid x:Name="Grid_Ajout_Activite" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="24">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListeActivites}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Lundi"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Mardi"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Mercredi"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Jeudi"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Vendredi"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Samedi"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" x:Name="Dimanche"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding LigneDebut}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColonneJour}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding LigneFin}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border 
                    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomActivite}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? Does this seem doable?

<Style TargetType="Border"> as ItemContainerStyle is wrong. Either omit the TargetType or set it to ContentPresenter.
